# I cannot create kivy file that is working

Tags: python, kivy

I am the beginner and I just want to create a .kv file. However, when I create a kv file, the terminal show me the error as follow. I actually did install kivy using pip install kivy but I face this problem.

This image is the kv file I created, I don't know the problem mean and I cant find solution, please help.

#### kv file

[image: kv file]

#### main.py

[image: This is the main.py]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or text. Please copy and paste the relevant information into your original question so that others can more easily reproduce  your issue.

Comment: We need to see the code in order to know wat could be fixed.

Comment: Thx for the edit suggestion, I think I cannot create the kivy file, should i do additional install other than pip install kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) says:

> The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header,
> where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re
> using. For now, use 1.0:
>
> #:kivy `1.0`

Note that the documentation says ***should***. Not having `#:kivy` at the start of your `kv` is not an error. The software that you are using is incorrectly calling that an error. But to satisfy that software, just copy the line from the documentation as the first line of your `kv` file.